# How to change module name in bootstrap file of zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am working on the application that contains different-2 modules like html5, flash and i want to redirect user to corresponding module on the basis of the browser compatibility.

Comment: could you add more details? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best method is to write a controller plugin for that

```
class Custom_Plugins_Browsercompatability extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        //check browser compatability

        if($html5)
        {
            $request->setModuleName('html');
            $request->setControllerName('index');
            $request->setActionName('index');
        }
        else if($flash)
        {   
            $request->setModuleName('flash');
            $request->setControllerName('index');
            $request->setActionName('index');
        }
}
```